# gLiveView not working and cnode.service could not be found setting up node for first time

Tags: node, set-up

My node is syncing right now for the first time but i can't check the progress or node status.

GLiveView failed to load and cnode.service could not be found

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the port on gLiveView's env file?
Also gLiveView will not work until epoch 208 is synced as said here:

> A node must synchronize to epoch 208 (Shelley launch) before
> gLiveView.sh can start tracking the synchronization process.

For the problem with systemctl, are you sure that you've created the service?
Which guide did you follow?

Answer (score 0):

check

```
ls -lrt /etc/systemd/system/
```

for existing services, looks like cnode.service is missing from that folder.
Anyway you don't need the full cnode.service running to use gliveview, just set these two variables for proper gliveview functioning:

```
CONFIG="${NODE_HOME}/mainnet-config.json"
SOCKET="${NODE_HOME}/db/socket"
```